# Showing that two sigma fields are equivalent

Tags: measure-theory

Given two generators:
$$
\mathscr G_1=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in\mathbb R\}
$$
$$
\mathscr G_2=\{(a,b]:-\infty<a<b<\infty\}
$$
I am trying to show that $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)=\sigma(\mathscr G_2)$.

In my attempt, I've identified that both sigma fields will be the Borel field on $\mathbb R$. I'm just not sure how to prove they are the same. I've tried to prove their equivalence by showing that:

$$
\mathscr G_2 \in \sigma(\mathscr G_1) 
$$
and
$$
\mathscr G_1 \in \sigma(\mathscr G_2) 
$$

How would go through an exhaustive proof of this, do I pick arbitrary values for a, b and show that they belong the borel field?

Comment: You need to express each element of $\mathcal G_1$ as a combination of elements of $\mathcal G_2$ and conversely.  By combination I mean a sequence of finite or countable unions, finite or countable intersections and complements.

Comment: So for example what is $\cup_{n\in\mathbb N} (-n,x]$?

Comment: $(0,1] = (-\infty,0]^c \cap (-\infty,1]$.

Comment: $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} (-n,x] = (-\infty,x] $ So im still confused as to what we're showing here though?

Comment: That shows $(-\infty,x]\in\cal G_2$.

Comment: Therefore $\cal G_1\subseteq \cal G_2$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant So what you've said is that we pick a = -n, b=x, and we show that the union of these values is $(-\infty,x]$, this implies that G1 is a subset of G2 and so $\sigma(\mathscr G_1) \subset \sigma(\mathscr G_1)$. So this is the first half of the proof

Comment: Actually it shows $\sigma(\cal G_1)\subseteq\sigma(\cal G_2)$.  I guess you have a typo.

Comment: @GregoryGrant So if i'm proving the other way, does this example suffice:
$$
\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} (-\infty,n] = \mathbb R
$$

and this implies that $\mathscr G_2 \subseteq \mathscr G_1$

Comment: @dimebucker91: No, for $\mathscr G_2\subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ you need to prove that every interval of the form $(a,b]$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$. Your example shows that $\mathbb R$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have shown that both $\sigma$-algebras is the Borel algebrea, you know that they are the same. Things that are equal to the same thing are equal to each other.

IF you prefer a direct proof instead, your approach is almost right. What you need to show is that $\mathscr G_1 \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_2)$ and $\mathscr G_2 \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ (with subset, not $\in$).

Since (sometimes by definition) $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ is the *intersection* of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain $\mathscr G_1$, the first of these implies that $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)\subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_2)$. Similarly the second inclusion implies $\sigma(\mathscr G_2)\subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_1)$. And when the two algebras are subsets of each other, they have to be equal.

Comment: I still don't quite understand this, is this really a exhaustive proof? Why can we just say that since $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ is the intersection of all sigma algebras containing $\mathscr G_1$ that this then implies it is a subset of $\sigma (\mathscr G_2)$

Comment: @dimebucker91: When you have shown $\mathscr G_1\subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_2)$ what you know is that $\sigma(\mathscr G_2)$ is a $\sigma$-\algebra that contains $\mathscr G_1$ -- in other words $\sigma(\mathscr G_2)$ is one of the things that $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ is an intersection of! And the intersection of a collection of sets is always a subset of each of the sets in the collection.

Comment: (And it is not a _complete_ proof, of course. I've left out the part where you actually prove $\mathscr G_1\subseteq \sigma(\mathscr G_2)$, such as by showing that each member of $\mathscr G_1$ is a countable union of members of $\mathscr G_2$).

Comment: So a complete proof is to first show what you just mentioned, which was shown in one of the comments below the original question, then to argue your point here?

Comment: @dimebucker91: Yes. Note that this is if you want to ignore your existing knowledge (which you claim to have in the question) that $\sigma(\mathscr G_1)$ and $\sigma(\mathscr G_2)$ are both equal to the Borel algebra on $\mathbb R$. Otherwise, as stated, a complete proof would be to notice that two things that are both equal to the Borel algebra are equal to each other.